# The type initializer for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Security.UserInclusionList' threw an exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, vsto

In VSTO (Visual studio to Office) project I am getting following exception:

> Error:
>   type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Security.UserInclusionList'
>   threw an exception

What does it mean and how do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the Inclusion List to Trust Office Application Customization. Follow Enabling the Inclusion list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772070.aspx).